# Facebook Javascript, How to detect if user is a fan of my facebook page? While on my site?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-fql

I have the following JS code.

The code's purpose is to first get the users facebook id, and then using FQL check that id against my page ID and make sure the user is a fan.

The problem I am running into is that the only time the code actually works is if i login with my own personal facebook profile.   I think its because my profile and the FB.init appid are somehow linked?

Can someone take a look at this code and show me where I am going wrong?

My goal again is to use JS to first get the users id (thus their thumbnail image), and then cross reference that against my own facebook page to check and see if they are a fan.  If they are a facebook fan, then I will probably give them a coupon or something.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
//Connect to facebook with my app id..
FB.init({ 
    appId:'135445813195028', 
    cookie:false, 
    status:true, 
    xfbml:true
});

//Check to see if user is actually CONNECTED???
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        // USER IS CONNECTED
        FB.api('/me', function(user) {
            if (user != null) {
                var image = document.getElementById('imagez');
                image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture?type=large';
                var name = document.getElementById('name');
                name.innerHTML = user.name;
                FBID = user.id;
                console.log('Facebook ID:' + FBID);
                //assemble an FQL query to see if the guy is a fan of our page...
                myquery = 'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = 126923080686340 AND uid = ' + FBID;
                console.log('query = ' + myquery); 
                ///Run FQL Query to see if user is a fan
                FB.api({
                    method: 'fql.query',
                    query: myquery
                }, function(resp) {
                    if (resp.length) {
                        var IsFan = true;
                        alert('You are A fan!')
                        console.log('Visitor is a fan');
                        //show coupon code...
                    } else {
                        alert('Signed into facebook, but Not a fan!');
                        var IsFan = false;
                        console.log('Visitor is not a fan');
                        //show like button...
                        //once like is clicked then refresh the page...
                    }
                });
            //END Run FQL Query to see if user is a fan
            }
        });
        //Figure out if they are a fan...
    } else {
        // USER IS NOT CONNECTED
        alert('NO USER session, user is not logged into facebook!!!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I reckon it's a permissions issue. Facebook may not want you to be able to check a user's pages without permissions (e.g. through an app).

Comment: Hopefully you can't. It's not really any of your business.

Comment: Can't say if FB allows this, but are you sure the others or the other attempt you do have a console enabled ? otherwise your `console.log` command will fail and halt JS.

Comment: @tomalak, what do you mean its none of my business?  If you have a facebook page its reasonable to want to determine if a visitor on your website is a fan of that page?.   Almost like the like button, where it already tells the visitor if they like your page.

Comment: @gaby, not sure i understand your comment?  How do i view the console.log?

Comment: @user684844: No, it's the visitor's business. Not yours. If I go to a website I expect to be treated like anyone else, no matter what I'm a "fan" of, and I expect my privacy to be maintained in terms of what "pages" I'm a "fan" of. I don't want random websites being told things about me and my Facebook account when I go to them in my web browser. The "like" button tells the visitor _whether_ they like your page, but it doesn't tell _you_ that.

Comment: Here's a completely ready jquery solution:
http://codecanyon.net/item/like-2-unlock-for-jquery/2822035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FB.getLoginStatus` check to see if the user is connected to your application .. not to facebook.

But when the user is not connected to your application, the `.status` property can tell you the reason of the fail (*if the user is not logged-in at all, or just to your app*).

So the structure you should use is

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.session) {
            alert('connected to Application');
        } else {
            // no user session available, someone you dont know
            if(response.status == "notConnected") {
                // But user is logged into facebook
                alert("Not connected to Application, but is logged in to Facebook");
            } else {
                // User is not logged into facebook
                  alert('Not logged in to facebook');
            }
        }
    });
```

But you cannot access the ID of a user that has not authorized your Application.
Not through Javascript API.

Comment: Got it, so i have to make sure that the user has authorized my app, before the userID is shared.  Seems like something they should make public, but i can see why they dont.